# Unstable lazy-loading in updated Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lazy-loading

I've own some website, that I created in the beggining of 2019. Since that time everything was working perfect, but recently I realized, that lazy-loading in Chrome browser is behaving in very unstable way. This problem does not exist in Firefox and Edge, where everything is still working well.
By unstable behavior I mean working or not working after refreshing the website.

My js code looks like below:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var lazyloadImages;
  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
     lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy-img");
     alert("number of elements: " + lazyloadImages.length);
     var imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
       entries.forEach(function (entry) {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
         var image = entry.target;
         image.src = image.dataset.src;
         image.classList.remove("lazy-img");
         imageObserver.unobserve(image);
       }
     });
    });
    lazyloadImages.forEach(function (image) {
      imageObserver.observe(image);
    });
  } else {
  var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
  lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy-img");
  function lazyload() {
    if (lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
    }
    lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      lazyloadImages.forEach(function (img) {
        if (img.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + scrollTop) {
          img.src = img.dataset.src;
          img.classList.remove("lazy-img");
        }
      });
      if (lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
        window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
        window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
        }
      }, 20);
    }
    document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
    window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
    window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
  }
});
```

I added alert for testing purposes. When I refresh the website on time the alert returns the number of elements and lazy-loading works fine, and another time it does not display alert at all (even the empty list) and the lazy-loading does not work (no pictures are displayed, just the alt texts).
What could be the reason for that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked (in the dev console) if your function interferes with chromes built in native lazy loading mechanism (since around v75.xx)

Comment: Read more about https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/ if you use in your html the "data-src=" attribute this might be of relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for comments. Console displays:

```
[Deprecation] <source src> with a <picture> parent is invalid and therefore ignored. Please use <source srcset> instead
```

I load images in the following way:

```
<div class="product-container">
  <a href="sth.html">
  <picture>
    <source data-srcset="images/products/sth.webp" type="image/webp" class="product-img lazy-img" alt="sth">
    <source data-srcset="images/products/sth.png" type="image/png" class="product-img lazy-img" alt="sth">
    <img data-src="images/products/sth.png" class="product-img lazy-img" alt="sth">
  </picture>
  </a>
  <p class="product-descr"><b>Sth</b></p>
</div>
```

It was working for long time properly.

So it means, that I should do it like this?:

```
<div class="product-container">
  <a href="sth.html">
  <picture>
    <source data-srcset="images/products/sth.webp" type="image/webp" class="product-img" loading="lazy" alt="sth">
    <source data-srcset="images/products/sth.png" type="image/png" class="product-img" loading="lazy" alt="sth">
    <img data-src="images/products/sth.png" class="product-img" loading="lazy" alt="sth">
  </picture>
  </a>
  <p class="product-descr"><b>Sth</b></p>
</div>
```

But what would be with the other browsers? And it still does not resolve the warning from console.